# How to replace a particular argument value in a shell script?

Tags: shell, ksh

I am running a shell script which is a common startup script for many jobs. It accepts 5-9 parameters. In some cases, I get a string `'/'` as an argument and in some cases I may not get it.

Now, whenever I get `'/'` as parameter, it needs to be replaced as `'usr/pwd@sid'`. I am new to shell scripting. Can anyone help me how to check the parameters and replace the parameter?

Eg: `startup_test.sh DEV filepath test.log sqlplus -S -L / @ sample_test.sql`

I save the values as `$1,$2...$9` and then execute the sqlplus to run the sql given in argument.

Also, since it is a common script, the place where "/" comes as argument changes.

I tried using 'if' condition to check each argument and replace it as `'usr/pwd@sid'`. But it was a long script. So please help me with this

Comment: You can check parameters in `$@`.  As per my understanding if `/` passed as a parameter to script. Does it need to be replaced with another string?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brief example of replacing any argument "/" with "usr/pwd@sid". I'm not a shell expert, so it's not super tidy.

```
#!/bin/ksh
args=( "$@" )
for ((i=0; i < $#; i++)) ;do
  if [ "${args[$i]}" == "/" ]; then
    args[$i]="usr/pwd@sid"
  fi
done
set "${args[@]}"
# verify that it worked
echo "$0 $1 $2 $3 $4 $5"
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh a b c / d
./test.sh a b c usr/pwd@sid d
```

Comment: Please use `echo "$0 $1 $2 $3 $4 $5"` (my arg2 is `*`)